# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in for loop

Tags: objective-c, iphone, exception, exc-bad-access

Can anyone enlighten me as to why i'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this chunk of code? I ran Instruments with Allocations and NSZombie enabled, and it said i messaged a zombie, but can't see whats up with it.

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"keys" ofType:@"plist"]];

//format: row, col
id myarray[4][13];

for (int row = 0; row<4; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col<13;col++) {
        myarray[row][col] = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
        if (col < 13) 
            [keys removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row<4; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col<13;col++) {

        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(5+col*65,5+row*65, 60, 60);
        NSLog(@"%@",myarray[row][col]);
        [aButton setTitle:myarray[row][col] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];         

        [keyboardView addSubview: aButton];
        NSLog(@"%@",myarray[row][col]); //I think it is this NSLog causing problem
    }
}
```

Here are the Statistics from Instruments:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        myarray[row][col] = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
        if (col < 13) 
            [keys removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

From the condition, `col` is always `< 13`, so `-removeObjectAtIndex:` will always be run. But this will `-release` that `[keys objectAtIndex:0]` in the previous line. Since `myarray[row][col]` shares the same reference with it, there is a chance it be deallocated — and that's the cause of the crash later.

You have to `-retain` the object to keep it alive, e.g.

```
        myarray[row][col] = [[[keys objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thank you! Memory management was never strongest suit... the Apple docs go into too much detail for my liking

Answer (score 0):

Have tried after commenting the NSLog statements?